# Loading Tiger & ACS Data Into CartoDB

Tags: carto, census, tiger, united-states

Does anyone have experience loading the pre-joined TIGER shape files and ACS 5 year data files by block group into CartoDB?

I have downloaded the data from http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-data.html by the 2007-2011 block group data, but the zip file isn't recognized in CartoDB.

Answer (score 2):

The descriptive XLS file bundled with that Census data is likely causing trouble. If you simply repackage the ZIP to contain only the 4 component files (.dbf, .prj, .shp, .shx), it should upload to CartoDB without a problem.